# product of Bernoulli and Categorical distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, bernoulli-numbers

I have random variable, which is the product of two random variables, derived such that.

$Z = X_i*Y$, where $X_i\sim Ber(p_i)$ and $Y \sim Categorical(i,\frac{1}{n}) $, here $n$ is the number categories. 
In my specific settings, I have 5 categories, and the probability of choosing any category is $\frac{1}{5}$.

What I am trying to do is, once I sample a category from using the category distribution, and multiply it with the binary variable {0,1} sampled from the Bernoulli distribution with parameter depending on the category.

What is the distribution of the Z ?.  Any way to derive it analytically ?.

Comment: By $Y\sim\operatorname{Categorical}\left(i,\frac 1n\right)$ do you mean that $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$?

Comment: Or did you mean to say $X\sim\operatorname{Ber}(p)$ and that $Y$ is an arbitrary distribution on $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$?

Comment: @Math1000 . Yes, Y is uniformly distributed between ${1,2,..,n}$ i.e. the probability of choosing a category is $\frac{1}{n}$.  The success probability of the Bernoulli distribution depends on the value of the category. In my settings, the categories range from $1..5$, and the Bernoulli probability is different for 1,2,3,4, and 5.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i\sim\operatorname{Ber}(p_i)$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$ be independent and $Y$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\ldots n\}$, independent of the $X_i$. Define
$$Z = \sum_{i=1}^n X_iY. $$
Then
$$\mathbb P(Z=0) =\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{X_i=0,Y=i\}\right) =  \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (1-p_i) $$
and for $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$,
$$\mathbb P(Z=i) = \mathbb P(X_i=1, Y=j) = \frac{p_i}n. $$

Comment: Hi, I added a comment above.  The success probability for the Bernoulli depends on the category.

Comment: Okay, so I think really you mean that $X_i$, $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$ are $\operatorname{Ber}(p_i)$ random variables.

Comment: Yup.  That is correct.  In that case, is it possible to write the product distribution analytically ?

Comment: You should update the question so it asks what you actually are trying to find :)